# Binding CommandBinding.Executed To a Method / EventHandler in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

i was just looking for a nice solution to bind the Application.Save Command to my viewModel and thought about this:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding  Command="Save" Executed="{Binding SaveCommandAction}"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

And my ViewModel

```
public ExecutedRoutedEventHandler SaveCommandAction => Save;
public void Save(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do Something...
}
```

result => It doesn't work... And I don't know why. You'll get an InvalidCastException saying, that he can not convert "System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo" To "System.Reflection.MethodInfo"...
The CommandBinding.Executed Property is of type ExecutedRoutedEventHandler.

Does anyone here know what kind of WPF magic raises this Exception?
I know that this solution is kind of dirty but It's actually a very simple one.

Comment: Why you dont want to bind VM command to this bindings?

Comment: Because I have a lot of ViewModels using the Application.Save Command but they should all be handled in the MainViewModel, which is the DataContext of the Window shown above.
I know there are a lot ways to solve this problem, but I actually want to know why this way is not working^^